# How can I make dhcpcd ignore an interface?

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp, raspbian-buster

There are two NICs eth0 and eth1 (on Raspbian buster).
For eth0 DHCP is used which works fine.
eth1 is supposed to be up but otherwise go untouched (NO static address since I‘m trying to setup my own PPPoE server on eth1).

Setting eth1 to manual in /etc/network/interfaces doesnˋt work as it also gets an address. It seems the way NICs are configured has changed since wheezer but all examples I found relate only to configuration of static addresses.

So how can DHCP (eth0) and manual (eth1) be configured at the same time?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcpcd.conf on here. Those are the two things that control this stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See **Prevent dhcpcd from configuring an interface** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Add `denyinterfaces eth1` to the end of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (but above any other added interface lines).

NOTE `eth1` may result in unpredictable results, as there will be a race condition in the enumeration of the interfaces. You should use **Predictable Network Interface Names**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.